# split column to two according dataframe values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like:

```
library(tidyverse)

tib <- tibble(Dis = c("One", "One", "Two", "Three", "Three"),
             Spray = c("F1", "F1", "F2", "other", "nj"),
             freq= c(80, 20, 1.34, 15.3, 20.2),
             Nom = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D") )
```

and I have a dataframe:

```
f <- c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7")
s <- c("other", "nj", "na", "ker", "dsf", "dsf", "rth")

fs <- data.frame(f, s)
```

As you can see the dataframe contains the values of Dis and Spray columns. Every one corresponds to the other.

I want to split the Spray column to two columns according to the data frame.

So, I want the result:

```
Dis   Spray  freq  Nom    f     s 
<chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 One   F1    80    A    F1    other
2 One   F1    20    B    F1    other
3 Two   F2    1.34  C    F2    nj
4 Three other 15.3  C    F1    other
5 Three nj    20.2  D    F2    other
```

General, I have created the dataframe of f and s to use it as a list with corresponding values. The size of this dataframe with the size of initial tib dataframe will be different!

Comment: I don't see common values between the `tib` ans `fs` dataframes. Which column in `tib` should correspond to which column in `fs`? I don't see either how the `Spray` column gets splited in two columns in your desired output.

Comment: it might me me, but i nee so logical approach how you get from your input to your desired output. Could you explain a little bit more? For example why `Spray` in the output gets (imo seemingly random) values from `s` ?

Comment: @Wimpel:Sorry, typo from previous attemp., I corrected the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to split the column, but you can use a combination of `left_join()` and `mutate()` to achieve the desired output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tib %>% 
    left_join(fs, by = c("Spray" = "s"))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   Dis   Spray  freq Nom   f    
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 One   F1    80    A     <NA> 
#> 2 One   F1    20    B     <NA> 
#> 3 Two   F2     1.34 C     <NA> 
#> 4 Three other 15.3  C     F1   
#> 5 Three nj    20.2  D     F2
```

```r
tib %>% 
    left_join(fs, by = c("Spray" = "s")) %>% 
    left_join(fs, by = c("Spray" = "f"))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>   Dis   Spray  freq Nom   f     s    
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 One   F1    80    A     <NA>  other
#> 2 One   F1    20    B     <NA>  other
#> 3 Two   F2     1.34 C     <NA>  nj   
#> 4 Three other 15.3  C     F1    <NA> 
#> 5 Three nj    20.2  D     F2    <NA>
```

```r
# Desired output
tib %>% 
    left_join(fs, by = c("Spray" = "s")) %>% 
    left_join(fs, by = c("Spray" = "f")) %>% 
    mutate(f = if_else(is.na(f), Spray, f), 
           s = if_else(is.na(s), Spray, s))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>   Dis   Spray  freq Nom   f     s    
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 One   F1    80    A     F1    other
#> 2 One   F1    20    B     F1    other
#> 3 Two   F2     1.34 C     F2    nj   
#> 4 Three other 15.3  C     F1    other
#> 5 Three nj    20.2  D     F2    nj
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It shows error in trhe last piece of code when you use the mutate. `Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `f`.
x `false` must be a character vector, not a `factor` object.
ℹ Input `f` is `if_else(is.na(f), Spray, f)`.`

Comment: Inside the `if_else()` change the last argument from `f` to `as.character(f)`. The `s` column will probably need this too.

Answer (score 0):

something like this? (I think your expected output is of in row 5, if not I dont know what you are looking for :p)

```
tib$f <- NA
tib$s <- NA
c <- 1

for (i in tib$Spray){
  if (i %in% f){
    tib$f[c] <- i
    is <- match(i,f)
    tib$s[c] <- s[is]
    c <- c + 1
  }
  else{
    is <- match(i,s)
    tib$f[c] <- f[is]
    tib$s[c] <- i
    c <- c + 1
  }
}
```